# Displaying record in row wise with specific size

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How to display the Tiles like below

Suppose I have 10 records.

```
   First row- 3 tiles
   Second row - 3 Tiles
   Third row -3 Tiles
   Last row- 1 Tiles
```

But In my case it appears one below the another

```
Tile1
tile 2
 ;;
Tile10
```

---

```
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.incentiveList}" var="inc">
        <div class="slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center tileMenuItemCard">
            <div class="uiMenuItem forceCommunityTileMenuItem" data-aura-class="uiMenuItem forceCommunityTileMenuItem">
                <span class="navTileLink" href="/partnersnew/s/incentivedetails" role="menuitem" data-special-link="true">
                    <div class="tileLabel" onclick="{!c.handleClick}">{!inc.Name}</div> 
                    <div class="slds-align--absolute-center imagePreview" clas="backImage" style="{!'background-image: url('+inc.Image_Url__c+'); height:150px;'}">

                    </div>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
</aura:iteration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use lightning:layout and lightning:layoutItem:

```
<lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
     <aura:iteration items="{!v.incentiveList}" var="inc">
        <lightning:layoutItem size="4">
            <div class="slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center tileMenuItemCard">
                <div class="uiMenuItem forceCommunityTileMenuItem" data-aura-class="uiMenuItem forceCommunityTileMenuItem">
                    <span class="navTileLink" href="/partnersnew/s/incentivedetails" role="menuitem" data-special-link="true">
                        <div class="tileLabel" onclick="{!c.handleClick}">{!inc.Name}</div> 
                        <div class="slds-align--absolute-center imagePreview" clas="backImage" style="{!'background-image: url('+inc.Image_Url__c+'); height:150px;'}">

                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:layout>
```

Check the documentation for [lightning:layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:layout) and [lightning:layoutItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:layoutItem/example) for details.